# FCM Listview but I can not list

Tags: java

**I can not show listview from fcm data notification 
where i did error ı didn't understand 
show time but don't show title **

```
setContentView(R.layout.fcm_show);

    listshow= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    String  title =getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
    String zaman = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    String  body =getIntent().getStringExtra("body");

    ArrayAdapter<String> veriAdaptoru=new ArrayAdapter<String>

            (this, R.layout.fcm_popup, R.id.tv_output, Collections.singletonList(title));

    listshow.setAdapter(veriAdaptoru);

    veriAdaptoru.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This should help -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: İ'm sorry ı don't know english very good

Comment: ı want to show listview from fcm but